# How to dynamically allocate a fixed runtime-sized array?

Tags: rust

I'm essentially looking for `malloc`/`free` in Rust.

I found `alloc::heap`, but when I try to use it I get the following error:

```
main.rs:1:1: 1:19 error: unstable feature                     
main.rs:1 ![feature(alloc)]
note: this feature may not be used in the stable release channel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a nightly Rust or you will have to use `libc::funcs::c95::stdlib::malloc(size: size_t)` from the [libc crate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/libc/funcs/c95/stdlib/fn.malloc.html). You'll have to [transmute](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) the result of course.

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that `malloc` will use the same underlying allocator as the standard library, which uses jemalloc in most cases. So long as you never attempt to "cross the streams", having multiple allocators isn't likely to cause any issues in practice, but is good to know about.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in high-level Rust (RAII, memory safety, bounds checking), you should allocate by creating a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html). You can optionally use [`into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) to disable resizing the container. See the book's [FFI example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/ffi.html) (specifically the `uncompress` function) for an example of using `Vec` as an allocator.

Comment: @xiver77 `Vec` is used as a defacto allocator though. Simply create a `Vec<u8>` [with the desired size](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) and then you can treat it as a slice or convert it to raw pointers.

Comment: @Shepmaster While I wonder what makes you call it "de facto", if you're going get the raw pointer from the storage and break the type system to do interesting things, why not just start with a raw pointer and raw memory. It's just my personal preference, though.

Comment: @xiver77 *de facto* means "in fact, or in effect, whether by right or not"; if people are using `Vec` as an allocator, I think it's appropriate to call it such. It's a stable way to allocate a chunk of memory that is built in to the standard library.